# Problems using the method `write_dimacs` of igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have problems using the method `write_dimacs` of the [igraph](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#write_dimacs) python library:

For some reasons which I don't understand, when I try to use it I get the error: `KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'` (see full output below).

Here is a sample code snippet that reproduces the error on my system (mac os x 10.10.5, python 3.5.1, python-igraph-0.7.1.post6):

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph.Read_Edgelist("graph3.txt")

print(g)

# This works fine
g.write_adjacency("graph4.txt")

# This gives the error
g.write_dimacs("graph5.txt")
```

I get the same error also if I explicitly pass the other arguments to the method, like in: `g.write_dimacs("graph5.txt", 1)`

**Output:**

---

```
IGRAPH D--- 15 22 --
+ edges:
1->2 1->8 1->11 1->14 2->3 2->6 3->4 4->5 5->4 5->1 6->4 6->7 7->4 8->9 8->11
8->12 9->10 10->9 10->5 11->12 12->13 13->10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    g.write_dimacs("graph5.txt")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/igraph/__init__.py", line 1676, in write_dimacs
KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'
```

Does anybody know what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the original DIMACS file. Judging from igraph's output, the original DIMACS file was read in a way that vertex zero is an isolated vertex.

Comment: @Tamás Vertex zero does not exist in the original DIMACS file, because the format specify that the first label must be 1. The input file is identical to the written but vertex labels starts from 1: [(1, 2), (1, 8), (1, 11), (1 ,14) ...]

Comment: Still, I need to see your original file to check what igraph does with it - otherwise I can't help. Trying with a random DIMACS file that I have created by hand seems to work.

Comment: @Tamás I was just updating the post with the file when I decided to try it again and now it works perfectly. Obviously I must have made some mistakes that I cannot reproduce. All's well that ends well (now I'm playing with write_svg ... adding g.vs["size"] ... but this will be another question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write_dimacs` method is for writing igraph graphs in the [DIMACS maximum flow problem format](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/DIMACS_maxf.htm). This format requires you to:

- specify the `source` vertex of the maximum flow problem
- specify the `target` vertex of the maximum flow problem
- specify the capacities of the edges

The source and target vertices are defined from the `source` and `target` attributes of the graph. The capacities are assumed to come from the `capacity` edge attribute. igraph's documentation has a bug here: the documentation says that if the `capacity` attribute is missing, it will simply assume that all the capacities are equal to 1, but this is not the case - you need to pass the capacities explicitly, or provide the name of an edge attribute that specifies the edge capacities.

In your case, the easiest way to get it working is as follows:

```
g.write_dimacs("graph5.txt", source=0, target=1, capacity=[1]*g.ecount())
```

where I have simply defined two arbitrary vertices as source and target.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I must admit that I believed the docs and did not tried to set `capacity`. I still have some issues with the labels in the written file (as far as I know DIMACS labels should start from 1) and I updated my question accordingly. If you have some other insight I will appreciate but I consider you answer correct, thanks again.